# R: find largest interval in dates with condition

Tags: r, date

I have a data frame with date and price. For some dates, price is `NA`. I'm trying to find the largest interval in dates between "last" (in a continuous sequence) `NA` price and last non-NA price. I'm completely lost - I suspect `difftime` needs to be used but I cannot come up with a condition for this.

E.g.:

```
 DF = structure(list(rollup_date = c("2017-05-01 00:00:00", "2017-05-02 00:00:00", 
"2017-05-03 00:00:00", "2017-05-04 00:00:00", "2017-05-05 00:00:00", 
"2017-05-06 00:00:00", "2017-05-07 00:00:00", "2017-05-08 00:00:00", 
"2017-05-09 00:00:00", "2017-05-10 00:00:00", "2017-05-11 00:00:00", 
"2017-05-12 00:00:00", "2017-05-13 00:00:00", "2017-05-14 00:00:00", 
"2017-05-15 00:00:00"), RegularPrice = c(6.47, 6.47, 6.47, 6.47, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6.47, NA, 6.47, 6.47)), .Names = c("rollup_date", 
"RegularPrice"), row.names = 145624:145638, class = "data.frame")
```

So, outputs here are 7 days (5/11 - 5/04) and 1 day (5/13 - 5/12). All solutions can be stored and then I just pick largest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DF$rollup_date = as.POSIXct(DF$rollup_date)
with(rle(is.na(DF$RegularPrice)),
     sapply(which(values == TRUE),
            function(i) difftime(time1 = DF$rollup_date[cumsum(lengths)[i]],
                                 time2 = DF$rollup_date[cumsum(lengths)[i-1]],
                                 units = "days")))
#[1] 7 1
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here is also a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, rollup_date := as.Date(rollup_date)][
  , .(last(RegularPrice), last(rollup_date)), by = rleid(is.na(RegularPrice))][
    , diff.days := V2 - shift(V2)][
      is.na(V1)]
```

> ```
>    rleid V1         V2 diff.days
> 1:     2 NA 2017-05-11    7 days
> 2:     4 NA 2017-05-13    1 days
> ```

#### Explanation

After coercion to `data.table`, `rollup_date` is converted from character to class `Date` (`POSIXct` is not needed here). Then the data is grouped by contiguous streaks of `NA` and `non-NA` values using the `rleid()` function, picking the last values in each group. The intermediate result is aggregated to 5 rows.

Finally, the date difference between each group is calculated and returned only for `NA` rows.

#### Prerequisite

The data needs to be sorted by `rollup_date` which apparently is the case for the sample data provided by the OP but was not explicitely mentioned.

#### Alternative solution

The aggregation consists of just picking the values in last row in each group. No other computation like `sum()` or `mean()` is involved. This is like filtering `DF`.

This can be achieved as well by returning the relevant row ids `.I` and using this to select the respective rows from `DF`:

```
DF[, last(.I), by = rleid(is.na(RegularPrice))][, V1]
```

> ```
> [1]  4 11 12 13 15
> ```

So, the complete solution becomes

```
setDT(DF)[, rollup_date := as.Date(rollup_date)][
  DF[, last(.I), by = rleid(is.na(RegularPrice))][, V1]][
  , diff.days := rollup_date - shift(rollup_date)][
    is.na(RegularPrice)]
```

> ```
>    rollup_date RegularPrice diff.days
> 1:  2017-05-11           NA    7 days
> 2:  2017-05-13           NA    1 days
> ```